# mqtt transfer speed much slower when data size increases on TCP

Tags: java, mqtt

I run a `mqtt server` on `raspberry pi` together with a `mqtt client` on the android handset. A data sequence will be transferred from the server to the client by TCP.

On the server side, `int[] result` has variable lengths (i.e. 512, 1024, 2048,4096,8192,...):

```
       private void processPublish(int[] result) {                                     

            String publishMessage ="myseq1";
            for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
                publishMessage += "," + result[i];

            service.publish(TOPIC_STATUS, publishMessage);
        }
```

On handset,

```
private class MqttCallbackHandler implements MqttCallback {

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_disable);
        connect_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.mq_disconnected);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, throwable.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        String message = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());
        final String[] messageArray = message.split(",");

        if ((messageArray[0].equals("myseq1")) ){
            xxxxxx;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        //
    }
```

I tried to find out the time consumption of the data transfer by:

```
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd :hh:mm:ss.SSS");
```

To my surprise, the time consumption to transfer data is increasing exponentially when `int[] result` increases.

length 512,   0.059 seconds
length 1024,  0.201 seconds
length 2048,  0.463 seconds
length 4096,  1.355 seconds
length 8192,  4.942 seconds

Please help, thanks in advance

P.S.  I borrowed `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar` as libraries.

Comment: There isn't actually a question here

Comment: question is whether the exponentially increasing time consumption is a normal behavior. To me,  a linear increasing time is more reasonable. Is it possible I missed some key configuration setting which caused this problem. Wish guru share their experience. Thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid `+=` with Java strings. Use `StringBuilder` instead. (I don't think that's the root cause though)

Comment: Thank you,  rustyx !! It solved the problem. now length 8192 costs 0.447 seconds.